# Azure Spatial Anchors unable to compile in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-spatial-anchors

We have included Microsoft Azure Spatial Anchors into our Swift iOS app using cocoapods, the app compiles and runs normally when the target is an iOS Device.

When the target is a simulator the app does not build.

[image: These are the error we receive]

[image]

Is there a way to ignore this pod and the code when running on simulator or a fix we can include inside the Azure anchor SDK

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm encountering this also. Our app contains a lot of functionality aside from ASA that would be good to test in the simulator

Answer (score 2):

Since ARKit doesn't support running in a simulator we hadn't included the x86_64 build in the pod. But it sounds like you've got a use case for it; it's entirely reasonable to want to validate other flows, and performing conditional exclusion of the ASA SDK surface area is going to be tricky. I'll add an item to our backlog to look at supporting ASA for simulators at build time.

Comment: Thanks Mark, would you please let me know if the item gets completed?